# How is it possible that np.mean takes so much longer than looping and calculating the mean regularly?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I've been building a neural network that uses a binary classification, and I noticed its running really slow. The code is:

```
predictions = self.neural_network.propagate(X_train)
rounded_predictions = (predictions > 0.5).astype(int)
accuracy = np.mean(rounded_predictions == y_train)
```

where x_train is of shape (16000,16) and y_train is of shape (16000,) 
When checking where the bottleneck is, I found that calculating accuracy using np.mean took an average of 0.55 seconds. I couldn't figure out what is taking it so long so i tried calculating it in a different way:

```
def compute_accuracy_score(y_train, predictions):
    """
        Calculates the accuracy score of the predictions made by the network.
        If a prediction matches its true label, it increments the count of correct predictions.
        The accuracy score is the correct predictions divided by the total predictions.
    """
    num_samples = len(y_train)
    correct_predictions = 0

    # If the prediction is correct, increment the count of correct predictions
    for true_label, predicted_label in zip(y_train, predictions):
        if true_label == predicted_label:
            correct_predictions += 1

    # Compute accuracy as the ratio of correct predictions to total number of samples
    accuracy = correct_predictions / num_samples
    return accuracy
```

This code ran it in an appropriate sub 0.01 seconds.
I don't understand why the np.mean took so much time compared to the simple loop.

This is the code I wrote to check the run time:

```
        def calculate_fitness(self):
            predictions = self.neural_network.propagate(X_train)
            rounded_predictions = (predictions > 0.5).astype(int)
            start_time = time.time()
            accuracy1 = compute_accuracy_score(y_train, rounded_predictions)
            end_time = time.time()
            print('Time to calculate fitness using compute accuracy:', end_time - start_time, 'seconds')
            start_time = time.time()
            accuracy = np.mean(rounded_predictions == y_train)
            end_time = time.time()
            print('Time to calculate fitness using np.mean:', end_time - start_time, 'seconds')
            print('Accuracy:', accuracy, 'Accuracy1:', accuracy1)
            self.fitness = round(float(accuracy), 4)
```

The accuracy isnt the same, neither is the run time: 
Time to calculate fitness using compute accuracy: 0.022114276885986328 seconds 
Time to calculate fitness using np.mean: 0.6563560962677002 seconds 
Accuracy: 0.559151625 Accuracy1: 0.6015625 
Time to calculate fitness using compute accuracy: 0.021242141723632812 seconds 
Time to calculate fitness using np.mean: 0.6553714275360107 seconds 
Accuracy: 0.441705 Accuracy1: 0.398875

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was using nparray of size (16000,1) which was translated to a 2D array for np.mean. However after using flatten() to get it to (16000,) it produced faster run times.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not including the model's time to compute the predictions? Here:

```
predictions = self.neural_network.propagate(X_train)
```

Because I ran the following snippet on my laptop with larger dimensions and still the process time is around 4 seconds.

```
_s = time.time()
a = np.random.rand(160000000, 1)
b = np.random.rand(160000000, 1)
_round = (b > 0.5).astype(int)
c = np.mean(_round == b)
_e = time.time()
```

Comment: ya im sure. Thats why it was so confusing. My debug got to such a resolution that i was checking run time for each line individually

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not accounting the time it takes to generate the predictions from your model inside the latency of the first method?

I have tried replicating your results, but I am seeing that the first method is 100x faster. Falling in the expectation range for a vectorized vs non-vectorized benchmark. See:

[image]